# how to remove an element from after()

Tags: javascript, jquery, html

I have this html elements.

```
<input type='text' class='req-in' name='fname'>
<input type='text' class='req-in' name='lname'>
```

and I have this script..

```
$('.req-in').blur(function() {
    if($(this).val() == ''){
       $(this).after('<p class="display">some text here for this field only!</p>');   
    }else{
       // I'm trying to remove the "p.display" for this only!
    }
});
```

I tried to `$('.display').remove();` but all the `p.display` were removed, how can I deal with it that for this only field that has `p.display` will be remove?

Answer (score 5, accepted):

You can use the `.next()` method:

```
$(this).next('.display').remove();
```

You can also check the existence of the next sibling before re-appending the message:

```
var message = '<p class="display">some text here for this field only!</p>';

$('.req-in').blur(function() {
    var $this = $(this);
    if ( $.trim(this.value) === '' ) {
       // if the next '.display' sibling doesn't exist
       if ( $this.next('.display').length === 0 ) {
          $this.after(message);
       }
    } else {
       $this.next('.display').remove();
    }
});
```